# Analogous Observable operator to Promise.resolve()

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs5

Is there an Rx operator like `Promise.resolve()` which
can resolve either an Observable or plain value to a plain value?

For example, I can do this:

```
Promise.resolve(3)
.then(function(val){
   console.log('val => ',val);
});
```

and of course, Promise.resolve() will accept a promise as well

however, I am having difficulty finding a analogous Rx operator,
something like:

```
Rx.Observable.merge(3)
 .do(function(val){
      console.log('val => ',val);
  })
 .subscribe()
```

except `Rx.Observable.merge` will not accept all values, and will fail as is above.

```
Rx.Observable.of(3)
    .map(v => {
        console.log('val => ', v);
    })
    .subscribe();
```

the above will accept a number but if you pass it an Observable, it will not unwrap the Observable.

Honestly, it is very frustrating that this is so difficult to determine. Having such a method/feature would allow for much more flexible code, because you could could refactor code to return non-observables and it will still work.

Here is the closest I have gotten so far:

```
// creates an Observable from anything, which can be unwrapped
Rx.Observable.any = function (val) {

    if (!(val instanceof Rx.Observable)) {
        val = Rx.Observable.of(val);
    }

    return val;

};
```

we can test it like so:

```
Rx.Observable.any([1, 2, 3])
    .map(v => {
        console.log('val => ', v);
    })
    .subscribe();

Rx.Observable.any('abc')
    .map(v => {
        console.log('val => ', v);
    })
    .subscribe();

Rx.Observable.any(4)
    .map(v => {
        console.log('val => ', v);
    })
    .subscribe();


Rx.Observable.any(Rx.Observable.timer(100))
    .map(v => {
        console.log('val => ', v);
    })
    .subscribe();
```

but I am looking for a more canonical way to do this...

Answer (score 1):

As you've noted in your question, there is `Observable.from` and `Observable.of`.

[`Observable.from`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-from) takes an argument that is either an observable, a promise or an array (or an iterable or array-like object) and returns an observable - with array values being emitted separately.

[`Observable.of`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-of) takes an argument that is the value to be emitted.

Unlike with promises, there is no single policy that suits all purposes - for example, there are operators that work with observables that themselves emit observables. With promises it's not an issue, as it's either a promise or it's not - and it wouldn't make much sense for a promise to resolve to another promise.

If you can formulate a policy that suits you, writing your own function that's implemented using `Observable.from` and `Observable.of` should be pretty simple. The first thing you need to decide is how you are going to treat arrays: do you want an observable that emits the array itself or emits the array values separately?

Comment: thanks, well in that case the naive answer would be to just return the array, not emit the values separately. In my question I conflated Promise.resolve() with the whole enterprise of promise.then which calls Promise.resolve on the return value then returns a new promise. A little bit confusing, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: That makes your `Observable.any` implementation a little trickier then, as you'll need to test for arrays, array-likes and iterables or `Observable.from` will turn them into observables that emit separate values.

Comment: yeah, with the array thing that you mention, that will mess up my Rx.Observable.any method, so I am back to square one

Comment: I think it's a mistake for the RxJS library to treat an array as an Observable. Big mistake. It order to get the Observable behavior you should have to wrap an object/array, etc. E.G: Rx.Observable([]); That is a classic API mistake IMO. They are trying to squeeze performance but at such a cost.....

Comment: I updated the last section of the question, I think I found a better way to do it given your feedback, let me know if you see any problems with it, thanks for your help

Comment: once you do Rx.Observable.of([1,2,3]); , I simply do not know however, if you can convert that to Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3]).....

Comment: I'd turn promises into observables, too, as emitting a promise seems weird, but it's really up to you. I don't think there's a single, correct policy.

Comment: yeah, I agree, it depends on what you want to do

Comment: BTW, `Rx.Observable.of([1, 2, 3]).mergeMap(value => value)` will be the same as `Rx.Observable.from([1, 2, 3])` (or `flatMap` - `mergeMap` is the RxJS5 alias).